# XML behaviour changes from Android 2.3 to 4.1?

Tags: android, xml, dom, w3c

I want to ask if anyone knows, if something changed with the behaviour of org.w3c from Android 2.3 to 4.1

I have an XML Node :

```
<block nr="1" canceled="FALSE" lesson="TRUE">
  <subject change="FALSE">AS</subject>
  <room change="FALSE">1234</room>
  <person change="FALSE">Name</person>
</block>
```

I give these node as `Element` into a function where i wanna get attribute values

```
GetAttributeByTag(pNode, "block", "lesson");

private String GetAttributeByTag(Element pElement, String pTag, String pAttributeTag) 
{
    Element toReturn = (Element)pElement.getElementsByTagName(pTag).item(0);
    return toReturn.getAttribute(pAttributeTag).trim();     
}
```

On my device (Samsung Galaxy S Advance with Android 2.3) toReturn contains the same element as pElement, so I can return the attribute value.

But on another device (Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1) I got `null` with `(Element)pElement.getElementsByTagName(pTag).item(0)`

Did anyone have an idea why?

Comment: i assume pNode is block?

Comment: so the thing would be that getElementsByTagName does not consider itself as eligible for return

Comment: but it works on my device without any problems, and on another device toReturn = null.There must be a reason or not?

Comment: Looks like a bug fix between the two Android versions. element.getElementsByTagName should only include the elements descendants, not itself.

Comment: Ok, it seems so... thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like a bug fix between the two Android versions. element.getElementsByTagName should only include the elements descendants, not itself.